# Unable to delete Amazon EBS snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am unable to delete an Amazon EBS snapshot because the console says that:

```
The snapshot snap-xyz is currently in use by ami-1234
```

I made the snapshot with the intention of moving the server between accounts, which I have done, but now do not wish to keep the snapshot (incurring charges in this account).

The documentation I can find indicates that to remove the snapshot the server must be no longer required.

Is there a way to separate the two, keep the server and delete the snapshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are receiving is not because the snapshot is tied to your server. It's because the snapshot is tied to an AMI image.

Three terms to be aware of:

- EC2 instance - this is the actual server
- EBS snapshot - this is a backup of a single EBS volume (disk)
- AMI image - this is a backup of an entire EC2 instance

EBS snapshots and AMI images are not linked to your EC2 instance. You can freely delete them and preserve your EC2 instance (server).

However, when you create an AMI image, AWS will also create EBS snapshots for the attached EBS volumes, behind-the-scenes. Those EBS snapshots cannot be deleted while that AMI image still exists.

So your error message:

> The snapshot snap-xyz is currently in use by ami-1234

is telling you that in order to delete snapshot `snap-xyz`, you need to delete AMI image `ami-1234`. Go do that first. Once that's done, you can delete the snapshot.